# Optional named group in Ruby RegExp

Tags: ruby, regex, nginx, fluentd

I'm using a plugin for parsing nginx log entries sent to fluentd, and trying to change it so it would optionally support another field.
This is the current REGEXP used for parsing the nginx log entry `config_set_default :expression, %q{/^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)")?$/}`

I tried adding the new field to the REGEXP like so - 
`config_set_default :expression, %q{/^(?<remote>[^ ]*) (?<host>[^ ]*) (?<user>[^ ]*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^\"]*?)(?: +\S*)?)?" (?<code>[^ ]*) (?<size>[^ ]*)(?: "(?<referer>[^\"]*)" "(?<agent>[^\"]*)"(?<http_x_forwarded_for>[^ ]*)?)?$/}`

This REGEXP can parse the log entry whether it has the new field or not, but still creates a named group for the new field, which makes the existing tests ran against the plugin break.

I would like to know if there is some way to instruct the REGEXP it should add the named group if a value for that group exists, and omit the group if otherwise.

Here's 2 examples of log entries, with and without the new field (respectively) -
`127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1 - [28/Feb/2013:12:00:00 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "Opera/12.0"`
`127.0.0.1 192.168.0.1 - [28/Feb/2013:12:00:00 +0900] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 777 "-" "Opera/12.0" -`

Comment: What do  the tests check?

Comment: The tests can be viewed here - https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/master/test/plugin/test_parser_nginx.rb. They basically try to parse a log entry, and I'm gonna add a new one that parses an entry with the new field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `(?:\s+(?<http_x_forwarded_for>\S+))?` optional non-capturing group after the last field pattern. That means the named capturing group should be inside an optional non-capturing one, and `\s+` should be placed before it to take into account any 1+ whitespace chars before the field.

Use

```
^(?<remote>\S*) (?<host>\S*) (?<user>\S*) \[(?<time>[^\]]*)\] "(?<method>\S+)(?: +(?<path>[^"]*?)(?:\s+\S*)?)?" (?<code>\S*) (?<size>\S*)(?: "(?<referer>[^"]*)" "(?<agent>[^"]*)"(?:\s+(?<http_x_forwarded_for>\S+))?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4b2kDh/2).

Note I replaced `[^ ]` with `\S` that is more natural to match chars other than whitespace chars with regex.